# Compare two files in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I have two files that i am trying to compare. File1.txt and File2.txt. File1.txt looks like :-

```
name1 12.12.365.237
name2 12.90.543.87
name3 34.47.26.230
name4 11.10.90.234
name5 10.11.12.15
```

Whereas my file2 looks like :-

```
10.11.12.15
12.12.365.237
11.10.90.234
```

I am trying to write a script to identify which IP addresses are in file1 which are not present in file2 and output the name and the IP in a separate file and convert it into CSV. so the desired output will be :-

```
name2 12.90.543.87
name3 34.47.26.230
```

I tried using grep like this :-

```
grep -Fxvf File2.txt File1.txt >> not-in-File2.txt

mv not-in-File2.txt not-in-File2.csv
```

But the grep command doesn't seem to be working as it gives the wrong output.It currently gives me the entire file1 as it is.

```
name1 12.12.365.237
name2 12.90.543.87
name3 34.47.26.230
name4 11.10.90.234
name5 10.11.12.15
```

What would be the best way to compare these 2 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP probably wants to enforce an exact **word** match instead of an exact **line** match, so replace the `-x` with a `-w` (same thing anubhava has mentioned):

```
$ grep -Fwvf File2.txt File1.txt
name2 12.90.543.87
name3 34.47.26.230
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach of using `grep -x` won't work because it is looking for an **exact match** whereas file1 has 2 columns but file2 has only one. By removing `-x` it will give output but will output full lines not just the IPs e.g.:

```sh
grep -vwFf file2 file1

name2 12.90.543.87
name3 34.47.26.230
```

To get just the IPs you will have to use:

```sh
grep -vwFf file2 file1 | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

**`-w` is very important** here otherwise `grep` won't detect mismatch between `12.12.365.237` and `12.12.365.23`.

---

You may use this better solution using `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR == NR {ips[$1]; next} !($2 in ips) {print $2}' file2 file1

12.90.543.87
34.47.26.230
```